# Int to Char array(part sums)

Tags: c++

I have problem with "tab" output. My program is going to show part sums. 
I want to save those part sums in tab array but it shows only first sum.

here is code I wrote:

```
const char numbers[] = { "1 2 3 4" };
cout << numbers << endl;
for (int i = 0; i < strlen(numbers); ++i)
{
    if (numbers[i] != ' ') cout << numbers[i] << endl;  
}
int sum = 0;
char tab[20];
for (int i = 0; i < strlen(numbers); ++i){
    if (numbers[i] != ' ') {
        sum += atoi(&numbers[i]);
        _itoa_s(sum,&tab[i],sizeof(tab),10);
    }
}
cout << tab;
_getch();
return 0;
```

How I can make it to show proper part sums like: 1 3 6 10

Comment: instead of `sizeof(tab)` in `_itoa_s` try `_itoa_s(sum,&tab[i],1,10);`

Comment: @ser3566309 See my answer. There is a ready to use solution based on your idea.:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has several problems. The first one is that function atoi will return an error because is will consider all string starting from &numbers[i] till the terminating zero. The other problem is that this in expression

```
_itoa_s(sum,&tab[i],sizeof(tab),10);
```

using tab[i] is incorrect.

Try the following code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cctype>
#include <cstdio>

//...
const char numbers[] = { "1 2 3 4" };

char tab[20];

char *p = tab;

int sum = 0;
for ( size_t i = 0, n = std::strlen( numbers ); i < n; i++ )
{
    if ( std::isdigit( numbers[i] ) )
    {
        sum += numbers[i] - '0';
        p += std::sprintf( p, "%d ", sum );
    }
}

std::cout << tab << std::endl;
```

At least I got output

```
1 3 6 10
```

Also it would be better to use `std::istringstream` instead of the for loop where you are extracting digits.

Answer (score 1):

[sizeof](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/sizeof) shows the size of the array in bytes, not the number of elements in the array.

Something like this will give you the number of elements:

`int num_element = sizeof(numbers)/sizeof(numbers[0]);`

Or a full solution:

```
const char numbers[] = { "1 2 3 4" };
int num_elements = sizeof(numbers)/sizeof(numbers[0]);
cout << numbers << endl;
for (int i = 0; i < num_elements; ++i)
{
    if (numbers[i] != ' ') cout << numbers[i] << endl;  
}
int sum = 0;
char tab[20];
for (int i = 0; i < num_elements; ++i){
    if (numbers[i] != ' ') {
        sum += atoi(&numbers[i]);
        _itoa_s(sum,&tab[i],sizeof(tab),10);
    }
}
cout << tab;
_getch();
return 0;
```

Although the above should work after replacing `num_element` into your for loops, I suggest you looking into a [std::array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) or [std::vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/)

Answer (score 0):

You are not retrieving the size of your arrays here.

Use [SIZEOF_ARRAY](http://www.cplusplus.com/faq/sequences/arrays/sizeof-array/#c) to get the size of numbers in C.

But you tagged C++, so consider using std::array<> instead of a C-style array (it will expose the size of the array for you)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, `cout << tab;` prints only the first element.

Secondly, instead of writing the result to `tab[i]`, create `int cnt = 0; _itoa_s(sum,&tab[cnt],sizeof(tab),10); cnt++` By that way, you won't have empty characters in you tab array.

Thirdly, you can keep `int tab[20]`, rather than to keep in `char tab[]`.

Forthly, `int num_elem = sizeof(numbers)/sizeof(numbers[0]);`(as said above).